# displaying computed values in textbox

Tags: asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Solar_Designing
{
    public partial class System_Estimator1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Click_St_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double x1 = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
            double x2 = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text);
            double x3 = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text);
            double x4 = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList7.SelectedItem.Text);
            double x5 = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList9.SelectedItem.Text);
            double x6= Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList11.SelectedItem.Text);
            double a = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList16.SelectedItem.Text);
            double b = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList17.SelectedItem.Text);
            double c = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList18.SelectedItem.Text);


        //  Number of inverters calculation
            double totalpower = Convert.ToDouble(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6);
           double charge = Convert.ToDouble(totalpower/c);
            txtCharge_Controller.Text = Convert.ToSingle(charge);
          }
    }
}
```

I write this codes to calculate for me and display the answer on a textbox but the code is not correct, showing that you can not convert float to string on the code line in the bracket (txtCharge_Controller.Text = Convert.ToSingle(charge);). I could not convert it please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to read:

txtCharge_Controller.Text = charge.ToString();